# Grid view display issue

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a data table which display like below in grid view and I done edit, update & cancel operation on it, it will work fine

```
ID        |  Title             |   Number    | State         
585344       issue 1               140024      In progress
```

But I want to display it like below in grid view and doing Edit, update & cancel operation on it, How to do please help....

```
ID-585344
Title-issue 1
Number-140024
State-In progress
```

Comment: can you please add one more row in output plus show us when you want to show operations buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of going for gridview go for Listview (as you are using .Net 4.0), you can easily achieve desired output.